# A custom filter is nowhere to be seen. But still there

Tags: support, bug, custom-filters

I have a custom filter named "ES5" which I could not find for some reason. Here is the list of custom filters:

The list of custom filters I have is:

- All
- fetch + api
- fetch + fetch-api
- fetch + javascript
- FP specific
- Frontend
- higher-order-functions
- Java + JS
- Java FP
- jquery + sql
- portal
- state machines

[image: Screenshot of the custom the the listed filters]

I did not remember deleting it. On the chance I have and forgotten, I tried to re-create it and gave it the same filter title: ES5. However, when I try to save that gives me an error: "A filter with that name already exists."

[image: Screenshot showing adding a filter title of "ES5" and the message that it already exists.]

The filter does exist apparently. I tried creating a filter named "test", deleting it, then creating another filter called "test". I did not get an error. Therefore, this is not an issue of re-using the name of a deleted filter.

I do not know when exactly the filter disappeared without being deleted. Nor do I know why it might not be visible.

It is concerning this can happen and I suspect this might not be the only one that might be affected. At a glance, I do not think there are other of my filters affected but I cannot be sure.

I believe this is a bug that needs to be investigated by developers. However, in the mean time, I am also interested in possible workarounds to identify missing custom filters.

Comment: Voting to close my question as no longer reproducible. The filter is back. I have not done anything with filters since I reported this. In fact, another filter I forgot about is also back. [I blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: You might want to make this a feature request, to not have this page cached; it's not a lot of load on the server to have this page current, when it's reloaded.